# Uniswap V3 SwapExactInputSingle keeps failing with string "STF"

Tags: uniswap, ethers.js, hardhat, swaps

I am trying to make a simple contract that swaps DAI for WETH9 using Uniswap V3, but whenever I call my function through a script I wrote, it keeps failing with string STF. I think I'm doing approvals correctly but I would like to know the solution. Thank you.

[image: Error Message]

swapTokens.js:

```
// but useful for running the script in a standalone fashion through `node <script>`.
//
// When running the script with `npx hardhat run <script>` you'll find the Hardhat
// Runtime Environment's members available in the global scope.
const hre = require("hardhat");
const DaiAbi = require("../abi/daiAbi.json");
async function main() {
    const DAI = "0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F";
    const MY_ACC = "0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266";
    // Hardhat always runs the compile task when running scripts with its command
    // line interface.
    //
    // If this script is run directly using `node` you may want to call compile
    // manually to make sure everything is compiled
    // await hre.run('compile');

    // We get the contract to deploy
    const MultiSigStaker = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("StakingWallet");
    const multiSig = await MultiSigStaker.deploy("0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564");

    await multiSig.deployed();

    console.log("Contract deployed to:", multiSig.address);
    const signerAccount = await hre.ethers.getSigner(MY_ACC);
    const daiContract = new hre.ethers.Contract(DAI, DaiAbi, signerAccount);
    const approved = await daiContract.connect(signerAccount).approve("0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564", 1000000000);
    console.log("Spending approved");
    let txn = await multiSig.swapExactInputSingle(100000000);
    await txn.wait();
    const accountBalance = await daiContract.balanceOf(MY_ACC);
    console.log("Transfer complete. Account DAI balance is:", accountBalance / 1e18);



}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

fundDai.js:

```
  // Hardhat always runs the compile task when running scripts with its command
  // line interface.
  //
  // If this script is run directly using `node` you may want to call compile
  // manually to make sure everything is compiled
  // await hre.run('compile');

  // We get the contract to deploy

  const DAI = "0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F";
  const DAI_WHALE = "0x6F6C07d80D0D433ca389D336e6D1feBEA2489264";
  const MY_ACC = "0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266";

  await hre.network.provider.request({
    method: "hardhat_impersonateAccount",
    params: [DAI_WHALE],
  });
  console.log("DAI Whale impersonated with address:", DAI_WHALE);
  const signer = await hre.ethers.getSigner(DAI_WHALE);
  const daiContract = new hre.ethers.Contract(DAI, DaiAbi, signer);
  const daiBalance = await daiContract.balanceOf(DAI_WHALE);
  console.log("whale balance:", daiBalance / 1e18);
  console.log("Transferring DAI to:", MY_ACC);
  await daiContract.connect(signer).transfer(MY_ACC, daiBalance);
  const accountBalance = await daiContract.balanceOf(MY_ACC);
  console.log("Transfer complete. Account DAI balance is:", accountBalance / 1e18);
  const afterBalance = await daiContract.balanceOf(DAI_WHALE);
  console.log("Whale new balance:", afterBalance / 1e18);


}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

StakingWallet.sol:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
pragma abicoder v2;
import "hardhat/console.sol";
import "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol";
import "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/libraries/TransferHelper.sol";

contract StakingWallet {
    ISwapRouter public immutable swapRouter;
    address public constant DAI = 0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F;
    address public constant WETH9 = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;
    address public constant USDC = 0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48;

    // For this example, we will set the pool fee to 0.3%.
    uint24 public constant poolFee = 3000;

    constructor(ISwapRouter _swapRouter) {
        swapRouter = _swapRouter;
    }

    function swapExactInputSingle(uint256 amountIn)
        external
        returns (uint256 amountOut)
    {
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(
            DAI,
            msg.sender,
            address(this),
            amountIn
        );
        TransferHelper.safeApprove(DAI, address(swapRouter), amountIn);
        ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams memory params = ISwapRouter
            .ExactInputSingleParams({
                tokenIn: DAI,
                tokenOut: WETH9,
                fee: poolFee,
                recipient: msg.sender,
                deadline: block.timestamp,
                amountIn: amountIn,
                amountOutMinimum: 0,
                sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
            });
        amountOut = swapRouter.exactInputSingle(params);
    }
}
```

I can post my hardhat config file too if it is causing errors, since I had to fiddle with it a bit to fork the mainnet successfully, but I don't think it causes any issues.

Answer (score 1):

It turned our there were 2 separate problems.

First one, was the thing mentioned by @Crypto_Rachel. The approval inside contract was only one of the two needed approvals. Before the trade, we also needed to manually approve OUR contract to get the token (DAI) from our wallet.

As I mentioned in the question, I've been trying two different swap routers: SwapRouter and SwapRouter02. After the first issue has been fixed, I've kept testing using only SwapRouter02.

It turned out, that SwapRouter02 uses different ExactInputSingleParams struct. It does not have delay parameter. With my usage of import "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol" and the struct it provided I should have used SwapRouter. Switching to that router resolved an issue and made my transaction pass.

If you want to read about that in details check this blogpost:
https://brightinventions.pl/blog/single-swap-on-uniswap-v3-with-3-common-mistakes